# The scope of そういうこと

Tags: meaning, usage

> A: 凄いな 僕にはそこまで先のことを考える余裕はないよ
>
> B: お前さんだって十分に凄い奴だよ。何の後ろ盾もなくここにいるってのは、そういうことだと思うがね
>
> A: そうか。君にそう言ってもらえると僕ももっと頑張る気になるよ
>
> B: ま、そういうことだから、お互いに頑張ろうぜ。今はともかく、いつかは決着を付けなくちゃならねぇんだからよ

To what exactly does the そういうこと in the final part refer? Does it refer to the previous utterance as a "whole" (which then links into the 互いに頑張ろう as the other character also said he was 凄い). If not, what does it refer to and how is it used?

Edit: My question could also be phrased as: what are the things that そういうこと can refer to in a conversation and how does one know which one the speaker is referring to. Plenty of times I've seen someone say something then use そういうことだから or そういうわけだから etc. to refer to what they just said before they continue, or it could be used to refer to what the other person in the conversation said. How does one know which one it is?

Answer (score 3):

The second そういうこと vaguely refers to the previous discussion as a whole, like "that" in "So, that's it for today". (Of course the first そういうこと refers to "お前さんだって凄い奴だ".)

そういうことで／そういうことだから／そんな訳【わけ】だから is a set phrase used when the speaker wants to wrap up the topic and finish the discussion, sometimes even without the conclusion. It's more true when this is preceded by まあ／じゃあ (≒So). The person who said 「ま、そういうことだから、お互いに頑張ろうぜ」 did not want to talk about that topic longer.

Reference:

- [Phrase of the Day - じゃ、そういうことで](http://lint.co.jp/e+/PoD/PoD.php?num=169)
- [会議で「じゃあ、そういうことで……」と言ってないか？](http://www.itmedia.co.jp/bizid/articles/0611/27/news052.html) (Describes how this phrase sounds irresponsible in business settings)

Answer (score -3):

> 僕ももっと頑張る気になるよ

「そういうことだから」 means: "since you will try harder."