# What is the etymology of the expression 「そんな」?

Tags: expressions

If its original meaning is "that kind of", which is what I think it is, why is it used to say "it can't be"? Is that the same word or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: If you want this reopened, could you edit the title and the content accordingly, so that it doesn't look like a duplicate?

Comment: I think this was already answered in kabichan's answer (and Nothing at all's comment) on the ["duplicate"](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38430/1628)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the same word used differently.

The "dictionary" meaning of 「そんな」 is "**that kind of**", "**such (a)**", etc. as you stated.

When 「そんな」 (very often pronounced 「そんなあ」 for this) is used as an expression on its own as in a reply or reaction to a statement, it can correctly be translated as "**It can't be!**", "**I don't believe this!**", "**Oh, no!**", etc.

But why, you wonder.  That is because when we say 「そんなあ」 as a reaction, what we actually mean is "**It can't be like that!**", "**I don't believe something like that!**", etc.

In other words, you could say that the expression is the extremely shortened form of sentences such as:

> 「**そんな**こと、信{しん}じられない！」 ("I can't believe something like that!")
>
> 「**そんな**こと言{い}われても困{こま}る。」 ("I'm troubled by a statement like that.")
>
> 「**そんな**こと言わないでよ。」 ("Please don't say something like that!")

By not saying the rest of the sentence, we can maintain our national obsession for ambiguity.  Just kiddin'.  Among us, 「そんなあ」 is a long enough sentence.  It conveys exactly what we mean to say.  We do not need to add the words when the native speaker listener/reader is already actually "hearing or seeing" them quite clearly.