# Meaning of そういうことだ here

Tags: meaning

The character lied to someone and then narrated

> 優しい嘘もこの世にはある。**そういうことだ**。

I understand that there are a variety of meanings that this phrase can add but I am unsure what it is adding to the whole here. For example, how would this line have been interpreted differently if そういうことだ was removed completely?

Comment: Where's this from? A lager excerpt can help to get a better idea of the context.

Comment: そういうこと is just him explaining what he meant in the previous lines. "That's all", "That's what I'm saying here." Or as a whole: "All I'm saying is that kind lies also exist."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

そういうことだ is a statement of agreement, "That's it", "That's true", "That's what I wanted to say", "That's how it is", etc. Here, the speaker is confirming with himself what he just thought, so "That's how it is" or "That's the way it is" would fit.