# What does そういうのができたんだよ mean in this context?

Tags: manga

In the manga strip below, they received a report that graphics used in their game are too explicit. I am not sure what he meant by

> そういうのができたんだよ.

What does そういうの refer to?

[image]

Comment: そう as in 「ああ、そうです。」; いう is 言う, and の is a nominalizer. If you already understood these concepts, the meaning should flow naturally. If not, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between そういう and そんな](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33141/difference-between-%e3%81%9d%e3%81%86%e3%81%84%e3%81%86-and-%e3%81%9d%e3%82%93%e3%81%aa)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel This の is not a nominalizer.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The problem is that I don’t know what thing の refers to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

そういうのができたんだよ translates to "Something called like that was made" or "It's something that was made/established (recently)", where そう refers to the word そふりん itself, and そういうの refers to the new organization ([ソフ倫](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%94%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%BD%E3%83%95%E3%83%88%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A2%E5%80%AB%E7%90%86%E6%A9%9F%E6%A7%8B)).

そーゆーの is an informal spelling of そういうの, which is the same as そういうもの.

- **そういうの** ≈ そういうもの: "something called so", "what people call so", "such kind of thing", "something like that"

  - **そう**: (adverb) "so", "this way", "such a way"
  - **いう**: (verb) "to say/call"
  - **の**: (noun) "thing" (the same as もの)
- **が**: subject marker
- **できた**: "to be created"
- **んだよ**: explanatory-no + copula + sentence-end particle

Comment: Thanks but I understand the grammar well. I just want to know what exactly の refers to here. Perhaps, this is the matter of reading comprehension, not Japanese…?

Comment: @JohnDavies の refers the organization in question, [ソフ倫](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%94%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%BD%E3%83%95%E3%83%88%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A2%E5%80%AB%E7%90%86%E6%A9%9F%E6%A7%8B).